# R tidyeval passing a list containing multiple character vectors to dplyr functions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

In this problem I want to map a function over multiple data inputs to create output showing frequencies of item responses.

First I create two data sets using the `psych` package:

```
suppressMessages(library(here))
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressMessages(library(psych))

set.seed(123)

data_input_sim <-
  as_tibble(sim.poly.ideal(nvar = 50, n = 1000, cat = 4, )[["items"]]) %>%
  mutate_all(
    ~ case_when(
      .x == 0 ~ "never",
      .x == 1 ~ "occasionally",
      .x == 2 ~ "frequently",
      .x == 3 ~ "always"
    )
  ) %>%
  rename_all( ~ str_c("i", str_pad(
    as.character(1:50), 2, side = "left", pad = "0"
  ))) %>%
  mutate(
    ID = 100001:101000,
    age = sample(c(5:12), 1000, replace = TRUE),
    age_range = case_when(
      age <=8 ~ "5 to 8 yo",
      T ~ "9 to 12 yo"
    ),
    gender = sample(
      c("female", "male"),
      1000,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(0.53, 0.47)
    ),
    educ = sample(
      c("no_HS", "HS_grad", "some_college", "BA_plus"),
      1000,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(0.119, 0.263, 0.306, 0.311)
    ),
    ethnic = sample(
      c("hispanic", "asian", "black", "white", "other"),
      1000,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(0.239, 0.048, 0.136, 0.521, .056)
    ),
    region = sample(
      c("northeast", "south", "midwest", "west"),
      1000,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(0.166, 0.383, 0.212, 0.238)
    ),
    clin_status = sample(
      c("typ", "clin"),
      1000,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(0.8, 0.2)
    )
  ) %>%
  select(ID:clin_status, i01:i50)

data_input_bfi <- bfi %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  sample_n(1000) %>%
  mutate(
    ID = 200001:201000,
    age_range = case_when(
      age <= 18 ~ "18 yo or younger",
      between(age, 19, 24) ~ "19 to 24 yo",
      between(age, 25, 39) ~ "25 to 39 yo",
      T ~ "40 yo or older"
    ),
    gender = case_when(gender == 1 ~ "male",
                       gender == 2 ~ "female"),
    educ = case_when(
      education == 1 ~ "no_HS",
      education == 2 ~ "HS_grad",
      education == 3 ~ "some_college",
      T ~ "BA_plus"
    ),
    ethnic = sample(
      c("hispanic", "asian", "black", "white", "other"),
      1000,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(0.239, 0.048, 0.136, 0.521, .056)
    ),
    region = sample(
      c("northeast", "south", "midwest", "west"),
      1000,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(0.166, 0.383, 0.212, 0.238)
    ),
    clin_status = sample(
      c("typ", "clin"),
      1000,
      replace = TRUE,
      prob = c(0.8, 0.2)
    )
  ) %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(A1:O5),
    ~
      case_when(
        .x == 1 ~ "very_inaccurate",
        .x == 2 ~ "moderately_inaccurate",
        .x == 3 ~ "slightly_inaccurate",
        .x == 4 ~ "slightly_accurate",
        .x == 5 ~ "moderately_accurate",
        .x == 6 ~ "very_accurate",
      )
  ) %>% 
  select(ID, age:clin_status, A1:O5)
```

Then I extract and sequence elements unique to each data set: the suffix of its name, the names of its item columns, and the names of its item categories:

```
data_name_suffix <- c("sim", "bfi")

sim_item_cols <- str_c("i", str_pad(as.character(1:50), 2, side = "left", pad = "0"))
bfi_item_cols <- cross(list(c("A", "C", "E", "N", "O"), seq(1:5))) %>%
  map_chr(str_c, collapse = "") %>% 
  sort()

sim_item_cats <- c("never", "occasionally","frequently", "always")
bfi_item_cats <- c("very_inaccurate", "moderately_inaccurate", "slightly_inaccurate",
                  "slightly_accurate", "moderately_accurate", "very_accurate")
```

`data_name_suffix` is a two-element character vector; I then create two-element lists (using `quos()`) to hold the item column and category names:

```
item_cols <- quos(sim_item_cols, bfi_item_cols)
item_cats <- quos(sim_item_cats, bfi_item_cats)
```

Now I attempt to map the output-creating function over the three inputs, using `purrr::pmap()`:

```
pmap_df(
  list(data_name_suffix,
       item_cols,
       item_cats),
  ~
    eval(as.name(str_c("data_input_", data_name_suffix))) %>%
    select(!!!item_cols) %>%
    gather(var, value) %>%
    group_by(var, value) %>%
    count(var, value) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    spread(value, n) %>%
    arrange(match(var, !!!item_cols)) %>%
    select(var, !!!item_cats) %>% 
    assign(str_c("freq_item_val_", data_name_suffix), ., envir = .GlobalEnv)
)
```

And it returns this error:

```
Error: Unknown columns `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, `A5` and ...
```

Which suggests to me that R is seeing the list `item_cols` as a single long character vector, rather than two separate character vectors to iterate over.

And here we reach the limit of my understanding of and experience with `tidyeval` techniques. I suspect that I'm doing something wrong with `quos()` and `!!!`.

Thanks in advance for any help, and I hope whoever reads this is safe and healthy during this surreal time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we could use `mget` to get the values of the objects

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
list(mget(str_c('data_input_', data_name_suffix)),
     item_cols,
   item_cats) %>%
     pmap(~ ..1 %>% 
            select(!!! ..2) %>% 
            pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'var', values_to = 'value') %>% 
            count(var, value) %>% 
            pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n) %>% 
            arrange(match(var, !!!..2)) %>%
            select(var, !!! ..3) )
#$data_input_sim
# A tibble: 50 x 5
#   var   never occasionally frequently always
#   <chr> <int>        <int>      <int>  <int>
# 1 i01     465          366        141     28
# 2 i02     489          336        147     28
# 3 i03     457          367        146     30
# 4 i04     433          385        162     20
# 5 i05     418          362        171     49
# 6 i06     420          369        169     42
# 7 i07     405          367        182     46
# 8 i08     361          401        194     44
# 9 i09     346          391        211     52
#10 i10     334          425        203     38
# … with 40 more rows

#$data_input_bfi
# A tibble: 25 x 7
#   var   very_inaccurate moderately_inaccurate slightly_inaccurate slightly_accurate moderately_accurate very_accurate
#   <chr>           <int>                 <int>               <int>             <int>               #<int>         <int>
# 1 A1                334                   278                 151               130                  75            32
# 2 A2                 18                    49                  48               197                 365           323
# 3 A3                 32                    51                  72               210                 353           282
# 4 A4                 48                    69                  60               159                 243           421
# 5 A5                 26                    66                  89               207                 340           272
# 6 C1                 17                    48                  82               213                 383           257
# 7 C2                 26                    85                  98               212                 361           218
# 8 C3                 35                    80                 102               272                 322           189
# 9 C4                296                   270                 166               163                  83            22
#10 C5                197                   212                 118               207                 167            99
# … with 15 more rows
```

NOTE: `assign`ing to create multiple objects is not recommended.  Instead keep the output in a `list` and make changes in each of the `list` elements (if needed) by looping over it with `map`

Comment: akrun, thank you. I can always count on you for a quick, elegant solution. Your help is greatly appreciated. Your point about not using `assign()` is well-taken, I need to let go of old habits.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to rename the list objects, within the existing pipeline. I  played around with `purr::set_names()`, but could not get it to work, I can't figure out how to feed `set_names()` the two-element char vec `data_name_suffix` without it returning an error.

Comment: @DSH Did you meant the `data_input_sim` and `data_input_bfi`.  If the output is `out <- list(mget(...)) %>%..` then `names(out) <- newnamesvector`

Comment: Yes, `names(out) <- newnamesvector` is how I'm handling it now, but it requires a step outside of the `pmap()` pipeline. I just think it would be more elegant to handle the renaming of the list objects WITHIN the pipeline, if that is possible.

Comment: @DSH if you want, you can use `setNames` i.e. `setNames(mget(str_c('data_input_', data_name_suffix), newnamesvector)`

Comment: That doesn't work in a pipeline, because in a pipeline, R sees `mget(str_c('data_input_', data_name_suffix))` as the second argument of `setNames()`, not the first argument as you have intended.

Comment: sorry ithere is a typo in closing bracket i meant `setNames(mget(str_c('data_input_', data_name_suffix)), newnamesvector)`

Comment: Figured it out, my implementation of `purrr::set_names()` was throwing an error because I had placed that function within the anonymous function mapped by `pmap()`. Once I moved `set_names()` outside of the `pmap()` loop, it operated on the list elements as expected. Thanks again for your help!